# onclick doesn't work as it supposed to work

Tags: javascript, html

I want it so if a user clicks on the panel itself it ticks the id automatically, but it just doesn't work.

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div style="border-radius: 0px; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; color: rgba(50, 115, 220, 0.0);" class="panel panel-price panel-addon" onclick="document.getElementById('5').click()">
      <div class="panel-body" style="color: #333;">
         <h2 style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600;">Sponge (SpigotVanilla)</h2>
         <label style="position: absolute; top: 2px; right: 17px;">
         <input type="radio" class="panel panel-default" style="position:relative; top: 0px; right:0px; border: none;" name="configoption[2]" id="5" value="5" />
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do u want check/uncheck on click?

Comment: It does exactly what you say you want it to do.  Can you better explain what is wrong with it?

Comment: Not uncheck, but I want them to check.

Comment: Just if you click the panel, it should click the radio, but it doesn't or atleast I don't see any changes.

Comment: Click the "Run" button in the question and then click the text "Sponge".  The radio (positioned over to the right) becomes checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without javascript, change the DIV that will receive the click for LABEL, so when the user clicks, the RADIO will be triggered:

```
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <label style="border-radius: 0px; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; color: rgba(50, 115, 220, 0.0);" class="panel panel-price panel-addon">
          <div class="panel-body" style="color: #333;">
             <h2 style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600;">Sponge (SpigotVanilla)</h2>
             <div style="position: absolute; top: 2px; right: 17px;">
             <input type="radio" class="panel panel-default" style="position:relative; top: 0px; right:0px; border: none;" name="configoption[2]" id="5" value="5" />
             </div>
          </div>
       </label>
    </div>
```

This is the best approach for your problem, but DIV inside LABEL is not a good thing, I recommend reviewing the HTML structure